# Is this set empty?

Tags: complex-numbers, nonlinear-system

Let
 $$M=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb{C}^3\;\hbox{such that}\;2\Re e(x_1\overline{x_2})=0,\;\;|x_1|^2-|x_2|^2=0,\;\hbox{and}\;|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2=1\},$$
Is this set empty? And thank you

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is *not* empty, since $\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac i{\sqrt2},0\right)\in M$.